# How to prevent python wheel from expanding shebang?

Tags: python, shebang, python-wheel

If I build a package with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, the resulting package expands the shebangs in the scripts listed in setup.py via `setup(scripts=["script/path"])` to use the absolute path to my python executable `#!/home/f483/dev/storj/storjnode/env/bin/python`.

This is obviously a problem as anyone using the wheel will not have that setup. It does not seem to make a difference what kind of shebang I am using.

Comment: Is this actually in the wheel? I mean, can you see your absolute path when you unpack it? I'd expect the path substitution to happen only after installation and then it just depends on your virtualenv setup.

Comment: Yes, thats why I get an error on another machine.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in wheel, there's an open ticket here: https://bitbucket.org/pypa/wheel/issues/135/bad-interpreter-lines-can-sneak-into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally narrowed it down and found the problem.

Here the exact steps to reproduce the problem and the solution.

1. Use a valid shebang in a script thats added in setup.py. In my case `#!/usr/bin/env python`
2. Create a virtualenv with `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 env` and activate with `source env/bin/activate`.
3. Install the package with `python setup.py install` to the virtualenv.
4. Build the wheel with `python setup.py bdist_wheel`.

The problem is installing the package to the virtualenv in step 3. If this is not done the shebang is not expanded.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem, even when skipping step 3.

Answer (score 2):

This should not normally happen. I'd suggest either:

1. Upgrading pip / wheel / setuptools and checking if it was maybe a bug.
2. Rechecking that the current shbang is something generic in the script. For example `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Here's a way I can't reproduce the issue:

```
paster --no-interactive test
mkdir test/scripts
echo -e "#!/usr/bin/env python\nprint('test')" > test/scripts/s.py
# add scripts/s.py to test/setup.py
cd test; python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

If you unpack that wheel, `s.py` will have an invalid/placeholder shbang `#!python`, but during actual installation, it will be changed to the proper system/virtualenv path.

Answer (score 0):

Using the generic shebang `#!python` seems to solve this problem.

Edit: This is incorect!

Comment: It's also incorrect. If you run a file with shbang `#!python` it will just tell you it's a bad interpreter.

Comment: The optional installation step in the wheel spec is supposed to replace `#!python` with a valid path (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#recommended-installer-features). When I put `#!python` at the top of my script, wheel correctly leaves it alone when running bdist_wheel.